# multiple sections to page. load different pages to each section

Tags: php, html, css

I have one page which is divided into sections. Ιn each section I like to load a page. If I have a form and I click submit button or a link I like to show the results in this section.

For example: I am in section "item1_section2" which show the php page `manage_team_teacher.php`. In page manage_team_teacher.php I have a form, if I submit the form or click a link I like to show the results again in section "item1_section2".  I am very confused on how to carry this out because all is in the same page (`index.php`). I'm new in PHP and I need your help. what do you suggest?

As you can see I try a lot of methods but I have problems: I try to GET from URL the name of page (in category).

```
<a href="index.php?category=manage_team_teacher2.php&amp;id_team=<?= $row['id_team']; ?>#item1_section2">manage</a></td>
```

above is an example of a link I tried to create

```
<div class="content" style="font-size:30px;">
                    <div class="section black" id="item1_section1" style="float: left; overflow: scroll; padding: 30px 0 0 30px; width: 869px;">
                            <h2>Section 1</h2>
                            <p>
                            sdffffffffffffffffffffffffff
                            sdffffff
                            sdf 
                            </p>
                            <ul class="nav">
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li><a href="#item1_section2">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#item1_section3">3</a></li>
                            </ul>

                    </div>
                    <div class="section white" id="item1_section2" style="float: left; overflow: scroll; padding: 30px 0 0 30px; height:690px; width: 869px;">
                            <h2>Section 2</h2>
                            <p>

                            <?php
                            include "includes/tests/multiple_choice.php";

                            ?>
                            </p>
                            <ul class="nav">
                            <li><a href="#item1_section1">1</a></li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li><a href="#item1_section3">3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section black" id="item1_section3">
                            <h2>Section 3</h2>
                            <p>
                            ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                            Wheresoever thou dost go,
                            Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                            When wilt thou return again?

                            </p>
                            <ul class="nav">
                            <li><a href="#item1_section1">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#item1_section2">2</a></li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
        </div>
        </div>





<!--########################--ITEM 2--########################-->




<?php if ($row['settings_key'] == background-color){
echo '<div id="item2" class="item" style="background-color: #'.$row['settings_value'].';">';
}?>

            <a name="item2"></a>
            <div class="content" style="font-size:30px;">
                <div class="section black" id="item2_section4" style="float: left; overflow: scroll; font-size: 18px; padding: 30px 0 0 30px; height:690px; width: 869px;">
                        <ul class="nav" style="float: left;">
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li><a href="#item2_section5">2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#item2_section6">3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <h2>Section 1</h2>

                        <p>
                        <?php
                        include "create_new_team_teacher.php";
                        ?>
                        </p>

                </div>
                <div class="section white" id="item2_section5" style="float: left; overflow: scroll; font-size: 18px; padding: 30px 0 0 30px; height:690px; width: 869px;">
                        <h2>Section 2</h2>
                        <p>

                        <?php
                        if(isset($_GET['category'])){
                        // include page about me
                        include($_GET['category']);
                        //else if is defined URL variable 'interests'
                        } else {
                        include('manage_team_teacher.php');
                        }



                        ?>
                        </p>
                        <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#item2_section4">1</a></li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li><a href="#item2_section6">3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="section black" id="item2_section6">
                        <h2>Section 3</h2>
                        <p>
                        ‘He scents thy footsteps in the snow
                        Wheresoever thou dost go,
                        Thro’ the wintry hail and rain.
                        When wilt thou return again?

                        </p>
                        <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#item2_section4">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#item2_section5">2</a></li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to also check that url is present

```
if(isset($_GET['category']) $$ $_GET['category'] ==bla ){
```

other wise if anybody set bla in url and it is not present than it causes

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='blabal') on line bla
```

Comment: yes i have different pages.. im in page1.php for example. when i submit the form i like to show me the results in the same section but the page2.php

Comment: i create something like this.. but this destroy the style.. if you know another method tell me please..!! if(isset($_GET['category']) && $_GET['category'] == 'manage_team_teacher2.php' ){
                        include('manage_team_teacher2.php');
                        }
                        else {
                        include('manage_team_teacher.php');
                        }

Comment: the better approach will be just get any parameter like `bla.php?category=teacher2` and check if its teacher2 than include relevant file imo

Comment: do you know why destroy the style (css) of page? when i refresh the page the style corrected

Comment: i am not sure ... if you have live link i can try   to help

Comment: i dont have.. thanx a lot my friend. i send you if i have news